# Help to create partition

Tags: system-installation

So when I create a new partition, I have 2 questions:
1. What file system do I use?
2. What mount point should I select?

I have already created a partition on my mac, but it doesn't show up on the list where you choose a partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should go with ext4
2. Depends. The best way is to split root (/) directory and /home directory. But if you have a small HDD I'll go plain /

I'm not familiar with MAC, there may be some extra step.

regards

Comment: So after I create the partition it gives me two options to choose from. Dev/sda1 ext4 or free space which is underneath that. Which one should I choose?

Comment: You choose sda1 ext4 and set it to /